# Help with this eingenvalues problem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the Laplacian eigenvalues for the Dirichlet problem in a right isosceles triangle $T\subset\mathbb R^2$ where its smaller side has length $c$.

I saw in an article that the eigenvalues  and the eingenfunctions are $$\lambda_{nm}=\pi^2\bigg(\frac{n^2}{c^2}+\frac{m^2}{c^2}\bigg)$$ and $$u_{nm}=\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{c}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{m\pi y}{c}\bigg)-\sin\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{c}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi y}{c}\bigg)$$ where $n,m \in\mathbb N$.

I know how to solve this question to the domain of the square with side $a$. The eingenvalues and the eigenfunctions in this case are:

$$\lambda_{nm}=\pi^2\bigg(\frac{n^2}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{a^2}\bigg)$$

and

$$u_{nm}=\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{m\pi y}{a}\bigg)$$

where $n,m \in\mathbb N$.

I need help to the triangle case which I found harder to solve then the square one.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about your formula ? For n=m the function is always zero but the eigenvalue is not.

Comment: *What* is the question? Where do you need help?

Comment: @daw it seems the op would like to know how is the procedure to get this solution in the triangle case.

Comment: @daw I need to find the Laplacian eigenvalues for the Dirichlet problem in a right isosceles triangle where its smaller side has length c. I do not know if the formula is correct, I saw in a article.

Comment: What's the reference ? Can you reduce the problem to the square case by "gluing" two right isosceles triangles to a square ?

Comment: @Sary how can I do this? I saw that lacked the hypothesis n greater than m.